# $ ℚ(\zeta + \zeta^{-1}) = ℚ(\sqrt5)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

Show that $ℚ(\zeta + \zeta^{-1}) = ℚ(\sqrt5)$ where $\zeta$ is the primitive $5^{th}$ root of unity.

I have seen a similar question asked, from this I gather that the quadratic polynomial is $ ^2+−1$, however I don't really understand how to conclude that it is equal to $ℚ(\sqrt5)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L/K$ be a quadratic extension given as the splitting field of a degree 2 polynomial $f \in K[x]$. When $\operatorname{char} K \neq 2$ the extension is determined by the discriminant.

Why? Well the roots of $f = ax^2 + bx + c$ are given by the quadratic formula (not that this is where we use the assumption on the characteristic of $K$), which only requires us to adjoin $\sqrt{\Delta(f)} = \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}$ - i.e., the splitting field of $f$ is obtained by adjoining $\sqrt{\Delta(f)}$. In your case the discriminant is $5$.

Comment: Oh interesting, is this a result of a theorem? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: @22560user Well it's more of a common trick, but yes I guess you could call it that, my answer includes the proof. You'll normally see it in the more general context of determining the degree $2$ subfield of the splitting field of a  (degree $d$) polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, here is a roadmap:

- $\zeta$ is a root of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$
- $\zeta^{-1}=\zeta^4$
- $z=\zeta + \zeta^{-1}$ implies $z^2=\zeta^2+\zeta^3+2$
- $z$ is a root of $x^2+x−1$ and so $z=(-1\pm \sqrt 5)/2$; no need to know the actual sign in $\pm$
- $\mathbb Q(z) = \mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$

Comment: This is great thank you @lhf.

Comment: I have a question regarding the unique subgroups also but I think I will ask this in a seperate question.